# Add HTML Tags to webpage using jQuery text() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on code where when a user clicks a button it displays a frame from another webpage using the HTML `<iframe>` tag using `JavaScript`.

Below is the code that I use to display to the webpage:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("p").text('<iframe src="webpage.html" width="450" height="475" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>');
    </script>
    <p></p>
</html>
```

Result:
`<iframe src="webpage.html" width="450" height="475" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>`

Sadly it just simply prints out the text without actually retrieving the frame. Is there any problem with how I am outputting the text or am I completely using the wrong function?

**I have tried...**
Removing the quotations ('...') around the tag

**Resulted In...**
The webpage being useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html in the place of text...

```
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("p").html('<iframe src="webpage.html" width="450" height="475" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>');
    </script>
    <p></p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

beware that text and html have different functionality :

```
    Text() : it replaces the text inside the html div or class specified but
                 but not the html

    html() : it replaces the specified dom of html div/class  ,or to be more specific
             the function called returns or set the content (returning an innerHtml),
             when you use to return content, it return the first matches,
             if not it overwrites the content of all matched elements.
```